# Write out author name even though it's the same name (BibLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently using BibLaTeX for my bibliography. And I have already written a lot of references in my .bib file. Some of them contain the same author, and since I'm ordering the bibliography in alphabetical order, some of the same authors are lined up right after each other - as intended.

But, let's say I have three books with author: "James, K." Then LaTeX writes it like this:

```
James, K., "Book name", etc. etc.
--, "Book name 2", etc. etc.
--, "Book name 3", etc. etc.
```

My question is: How do I make LaTeX write the full name, and not just the -- ?

Thanks in advance.